# Merge Accounts permission for a non admin users

Tags: account, merge

How do we grant permissions to non admin user to merge accounts in salesforce.

Note :

1. I gave delete permission for the user on account object, edit on opp,cases, contacts and also edit on other related custom objects. - no luck.
2. Later, I also gave Modify All permission on account object for the user. - Still no joy.
3. OWD is "Public Read/Write" on Account, opp, contacts.

Even after trying all these options, user gets the message " Insufficient Privileges. You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. "

Also, Please note that the user is not the record owner. But I would want a way to grant the permissions to the user to be able to merge the accounts.

Please help !!!

Answer (score 6):

Please see the following knowledge base article 000004461 : [Why do I receive an Insufficient privileges error message when I try to merge two accounts?](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004461&language=en_US)

> When you merge two accounts you are effectively deleting one of them. You can merge accounts if you are an administrator (modify all data permission), the account owner, or a user above the account owner in the role hierarchy and you have the appropriate user permissions.
>
> First of all there are some permissions that you need to check in your profile:
>
> 1.)“Read” on accounts
>
> 2.)“Delete” on accounts
>
> 3.) “Edit” permissions on opportunities and cases, if the accounts have related opportunities and/or cases.
>
> If you have all these permissions and are still experiencing the error you need to check the following:
>
> i. Are you in an unrelated role in the hierarchy and check if you have access to the accounts thanks to a sharing rule. If you try to delete either one of the accounts that you are trying to merge, you will most likely get a similar Insufficient Privileges error.
>
> ii. Sharing rules do not give users delete permissions, only read/edit.
>   While the sharing rule gives you read/write access to the Accounts, it doesn't give you the delete permission necessary for merging. You cannot delete an account you do not own, therefore you cannot merge two accounts that you do not own.
>
> iii. Check all account team member's access to contact/case/opportunity, and make sure they do not have greater access than the surviving account owner's access. Eg, if account owner has read access to opportunity/contact, but some account team member has edit access to opportunity, the error will also occur.
>
> If account team members do have greater access level, Modify All permission on Account entity would be required for a user who is performing the Merge process.

Comment: I followed all the steps with no luck. I enabled " manage user " for the user and then, user was able to merge accounts.

Comment: Interesting. Are permissions on the User Object set to private for either internal or external users? If so, that might explain why. Enforcement of sharing on the User object in Apex classes by default is something new to either SP15 or SU15 when classes have 'with sharing'.

Comment: The owner portion is important to understand. They CANNOT be at equal levels in the role if something is going to be deleted/merged. This can only happen when she is above the owner of the records merging, or she owns them directly.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue in one of my orgs.

PROBLEM:

- Users are unable to merge duplicate Accounts, even when the owner of both are at the same level of role hierarchy.

CURRENT STATE:

- Org-Wide sharing rules for Accounts are Public Read/Write.
- User's profile has create, read, edit, and delete permission for Accounts.

SOLUTION:

- Add "Modify All" for Accounts on the profile (or with a permission set).

In this org's use case, adding it to the profile was best because they wanted to open up these capabilities for all users of the same role.